# How to get Default coontent-Type Android volley

Tags: android, http-headers, android-volley

I want know how to get default content-type from header in volley android

```
      @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authkey", Agent_Name);
            headers.put("apptype", "android");
            headers.put("apptoken", gcmID);
            return headers;
        }
```

Here I did not mention content type,so how to get default content type.

Comment: what content-type you need?

Comment: simply add `headers.set("content-type","application/json")` or whatever

Comment: @NoumanCh i don't think i think the default content type is application-form-data

Comment: yes you are right dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   I just append text fields to the body and created the following function to do it in multipart :

  private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String 
parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"");
    dataOutputStream.write(parameterName.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + 
  lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.write(parameterValue.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd)

 }

 here mention multipart data format ,and text format as utf8,its working fine
```